# Postgresql - tree-like / Arborescent count-based query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, where-clause, crosstab

I have a postgresql table where some columns should be hierarchically ordered for a synthesis table export.

The expected result should look like this :

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai1UC.png)

Is there a way to obtain this kind of table ? As I understand, I would need to make a kind of "group by" only for the column 4, based on column 3.

Comment: We can not write a programm or script for you. We can help you when you stuck. Can you post what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, ROLLUP should resolve it.

```
SELECT big_category, small_category
FROM YOUR_TABLE_CATEGORIES
GROUP BY ROLLUP(big_category, small_category)
```

[Introduction to the PostgreSQL ROLLUP](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rollup/#:%7E:text=The%20PostgreSQL%20ROLLUP%20is%20a,tutorial%20for%20the%20detailed%20information.)